# Creating a layout of three fieldsets

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on the layout of a page that consists of three fieldsets. Ideally I would like for the first to span to 100% and the other two below it side by side with 50% width.

I'm unsure of the trick I need to do to make this work. I've set the two I want to 50% and display: inline-block; however, they are still displayed two 50% width fieldsets one on each line.

My code:

```css
ul {
 list-style: none;


}
a {
 text-decoration: none;


}
#inline {
 width :50%;
 padding : 0;
 margin : 0;
 display : inline;

}


input[type=submit]#loc{
 margin-left: 75px;
 display:inline-block;
}

td {
padding: 10px;

}

label{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: right;
}
.input input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.inputAdd input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <fieldset class= "spanField">
    <legend>Spanned Field</legend>     
     <form method="post" action="index.php" onsubmit="validation();">
      <label>Input 1&nbsp;</label>
      <input  type="text" size="20"> 
      <label>Input 2&nbsp;</label>
      <input  type="text" size="20">      
      <input type="submit" value="Add" />
      <table style ="display:inline;">
      <tr>
      <td></td><td>Input</td><td>Input</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td><button>X</button></td><td>Input 1</td><td>911 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><button>X</button></td><td>Input 2</td><td>911 2</td>
      </tr>
      </table>
     </form>
    </fieldset><br />
    <fieldset id = "inline" class ="inputAdd">
    <legend>Half field</legend>
     <form method="post" action="index.php" onsubmit="validation();">     
      <table>
      <tr>
      <td></td><td>Input</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td><button>X</button></td><td>Input 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><button>X</button></td><td>Input 2</td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <div style ="float:right;">
      <select >
      <option>Option 1</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Add" />
      </div>
     </form>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="inline" class ="input">
    <legend>Half Field</legend>
     <form method="post" action="index.php" onsubmit="validation();">
      <label>Add input&nbsp;</label>
      <input  type="text" size="20">      
      <input type="submit"  value="Add" />
     </form>
     <table>
     <tr>
     <td></td><td>Input</td>
     </tr> 
     <tr>
     <td><button>X</button></td><td>Input 1</td>
     </tr>
     </table>     
    </fieldset>
   </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the border is also calculated into the width of the elements, so your elements are not exactly 50% but a little more.

You can fix this by using `box-sizing` css property set to `border-box`:

```
 box-sizing: border-box;
```

Read more about all possible `box-sizing` properties on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp). You also need to float the elements (css: `float: left`).

I also noted, that you are using two elements with the same ID. Only one element should have an id, so please change your selector to use class like this:

```
.inline {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
```

and in your HTML:

```
<fieldset class="inputAdd inline">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your time and the explanation!